# Scala variable naming rules with underscore

Tags: scala

What are the rules to name methods and variables in Scala, especially when mixing symbols and letters using `_`? For instance, why `_a_`, `a_+`, `__a`, `__a__a__a__+`, `___` are valid names, but `_a_+_a` or `_a_+_` are not?

Comment: Note also that `_a_` and all the rest, with the possible partial exception of `a_+`, are discouraged.  `_` has many other meanings in Scala; using it inside variable names as well is usually visually confusing.  I only use it if the variable should never be seen (e.g. in the name of an implicit def that nobody is supposed to call directly); style guides tend to say not to use it at all, except possibly for `_a` as the name of a private variable matching a visible variable `a`.  (To continue the aside: I find `_a` visually confusing then too, so I favor `myA` instead.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the [very first section of the Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers):

> There are three ways to form an identifier. First, an identifier can start with a letter which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of letters and digits. This may be followed by underscore ‘_‘ characters and another string composed of either letters and digits or of operator characters.

It's not entirely clear from this, but the operator characters cannot be followed by anything else. Seen here (the pattern for the end of the identifier):

```
idrest   ::=  {letter | digit} [‘_’ op]
```

`_a_+_a` and `_a_+_` are illegal because they have another letter or underscore following the operator characters. However, they *are* legal if you surround them with back quotes.

```
scala> val `_a_+_` = 1
_a_+_: Int = 1

scala> val `_a_+_a` = 1
_a_+_a: Int = 1
```

Comment: The regex is wrong : _ is legal as a first character

Comment: @Dici that's the syntax for the rest of the identifier, not for the whole one.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html):

> There are three ways to form an identifier. First, an identifier can
>   start with a letter which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of
>   letters and digits. This may be followed by underscore ‘_‘ characters
>   and another string composed of either letters and digits or of
>   operator characters. Second, an identifier can start with an operator
>   character followed by an arbitrary sequence of operator characters.
>   The preceding two forms are called plain identifiers. Finally, an
>   identifier may also be formed by an arbitrary string between
>   back-quotes (host systems may impose some restrictions on which
>   strings are legal for identifiers). The identifier then is composed of
>   all characters excluding the backquotes themselves.

You can also see in the link the grammar of the language.